# Why isn't alt a valid attribute for <input>?

Tags: css, html, specifications

`alt=""` attribute isn't valid on `<input>` tags. Why this choice?

[**HTML5 Specification**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element)

I know that `alt` is meant to provide an alternative content if "main" content is not available, and since the `input` tag is there to actually input something an alternative text wouldn't be useful, but nowadays `alt` attributes are mostly used for accessibility purposes! If no `alt` or `name` or `placeholder` are present the only attribute to decipher the nature of the element would be the `type`. But what if multiple inputs with same type are present?

What do you thing?

Comment: `alt` is not "not valid on `<input>` tags". Where in the spec do you see such a statement? It only makes sense for image types... And where did you get the idea that `alt` is only used for a10y (accessibility)? If you care about a10y, a more natual choice would be using [WAI-ARIA](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/aria).

Comment: @RobW, did accessibility lose a letter while I wasn't watching? ;-) (a11y is the usual short form).

Comment: The HTML5 draft cited declares `alt` as valid for `input` (though only when it is in the image state), so the question is meaningless. It is apparently based on a misunderstanding of the purpose and function of the attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`label` is actually used for this purpose, for example:

```
<label for="name">Enter your name:</label>
<input id="name" name="name">
```

This form can give you all the information you need, and even a screen reader can figure it out :)

This is mentioned here in [Creating Accessible Forms](http://webaim.org/techniques/forms/controls), as well as many other sources.